# Turn _ids into Keys of New Object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a huge bunch of documents as such:

```
{
  _id: '1abc',
  colors: [
    { value: 'red', count: 2 },
    { value: 'blue', count: 3}
  ]
},    
{
  _id: '2abc',
  colors: [
    { value: 'red', count: 7 },
    { value: 'blue', count: 34},
    { value: 'yellow', count: 12}
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to make use of `aggregate()` to get the following?

```
{
  _id: 'null',
  colors: {
    "1abc": [
      { value: 'red', count: 2 },
      { value: 'blue', count: 3}
    ],
    "2abc": [
      { value: 'red', count: 7 },
      { value: 'blue', count: 34},
      { value: 'yellow', count: 12}
    ]
  }
}
```

Basically, is it possible to turn all of the original documents' `_id`s into keys of a new object in the singular new aggregated document?

So far, when trying to use`$group`, I had not been able to use a variable value, e.g. `$_id`, on the left hand side of an assignment. Am I missing something or is it simply impossible?

I can do this easily using `Javascript` but it is unbearably slow. Hence why I am looking to see if it is possible using `mongo` native `aggregate()`, which will probably be faster.

If impossible... I would appreciate any kind suggestions that could point towards a sufficient alternative (change structure, etc.?). Thank you!

Comment: No it's not possible, nor should it be. It's actually a pretty dumb thing to do when you already have the data in a naturally usable form. Named keys are really bad and just lead to really obtuse code. Also having the data in seperate documents should be an "advantage" with the inherrent lack of possibly breaking the BSON limit. If you really had to have one document, then you can always put everything into a nested array response. But the aggregation framework simply does not do "named keys". Give up the habit, it's a dirty one.

Comment: Sigh, that's what I thought too, @BlakesSeven. Thanks for the response. I shall think about it.

Comment: I also really don't get the point. If you are not actually aggregating things then you can simply read a cursor or returned array or whatever you have and transform the data in response. It's not like you are asking the expression to "remove" anything either, so there is little point in asking the server to do this. Another bad habit of people writing ridiculously overcomplicated SQL simply to to a data transformation that could have easily been done in the client. It's a new year, and new tech. Break bad habits and do something different.

Comment: Yes, well, I have a huge database with loads of documents. It is really slow to transform the data by looping through the documents in my JS. I believe native Mongo methods to be way more optimized and faster, hence. In any case, this is the one time I am trying to do something dirty, because I can't think of anything better (faster) for now without breaking a lot of things, but yes, I really should just push forth, :( Once again, thanks!

Comment: Other quick question, if you could so kindly help me, @BlakesSeven. Is it possible when using `$aggregate`, `$project` and `$slice` to return a specific element in an array of objects, to directly obtain only a specific field of the object (and not the entire object indexed at the indicated `$slice` position)?

Comment: [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/)

Comment: OK, it works! I just replaced `$slice` with `$arrayElemAt` and with the `.` operator, it returned the `string` I wanted rather than an `array` as was returned by `$slice`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like a said in comments, whilst there are things you can do with the aggregation framework or even mapReduce to make the "server" reshape the response, it's kind of silly to do so.

Lets consider the cases:

### Aggregate

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": { "$in": ["1abc","2abc"] } } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "result": { "$push": "$$ROOT" }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "colors": {
      "1abc": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          { "$map": {
            "input": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$result",
                "as": "r",
                "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$r._id", "1abc" ] },
              }
            },
            "as": "r",
            "in": "$$r.colors"
          }},
          0
        ]
      },
      "2abc": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          { "$map": {
            "input": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$result",
                "as": "r",
                "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$r._id", "2abc" ] },
              }
            },
            "as": "r",
            "in": "$$r.colors"
          }},
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

So the aggregation framework purely does not dynamically generate "keys" of a document. If you want to process this way, then you need to know all of the "values" that you are going to use to make the keys in the result.

After putting everything into one document with [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), you can then work with the result array to extact data for your "keys". The basic operators here are:

- [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to get the matched element of the array for the "value" that you want.
- [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to return just the specific property from the filtered array
- [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to just grab the single elment that was filtered out of the resulting mapped array

So it really isn't practical in a lot of cases, and the coding of the statement is fairly involved.

### MapReduce

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
  function() {
    var obj = { "colors": {} };
    obj.colors[this._id] = this.colors;
    emit(null,obj);
  },
  function(key,values) {
    var obj = { "colors": {} };

    values.forEach(function(value) {
      Object.keys(value.colors).forEach(function(key) {
        obj.colors[key] = value.colors[key];
      });
    })

    return obj;
  },
  { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

Since it is actually written in a "language" then you have the ability to loop structures and "build things" in a more dynamic way.

However, close inspection should tell you that the "reducer" function here is not doing anything more than being the processor of "all the results" which have been "stuffed into it" but each emitted document.

That means that "iterating the values" fed to the reducer is really no different to "iterating the cursor", and that leads to the next conclusion.

### Cursor Iteration

```js
var result  = { "colors": {} };

db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
  result.colors[doc._id] = doc.colors;
})

printjson(result)
```

The simplicity of this should really speak volumes. It is afterall doing exactly what you are trying to "shoehorn" into a server operation and nothing more, and just simply "rolls up it sleeves" and gets on with the task at hand.

The key point here is none of the process requires any "aggregation" in a real sense, that cannot be equally achieved by simply iterating the cursor and building up the response document.

This is really why you always need to look at what you are doing and choose the right method. "Server side" aggregation has a primary task of "reducing" a result so you would not need to iterate a cursor. But nothing here "reduces" anything. It's just **all** of the data, transformed into a different format.

Therefore the simple approach for this type of "transform" is to just iterate the cursor and build up your transformed version of "all the results" anyway.

Comment: Your last part on `Cursor Iteration` was/is exactly what I was/is doing. I have not changed it yet, because as I have realized, and as you have pointed out, it should be done by server aggregation. I agree that there is no 'real aggregation'. I am honestly just looking for a way to quicken the process. `Cursor Iteration` is proving to be reaaaaaaaally slow. Thanks for the input! @BlakesSeven

Comment: It's all OK now. I managed to successfully make it many times faster, >_<, without resorting to dirty tricks! Cheers!